# add time in rows of pandas data frame and append total_time in new column of data frame

Tags: python, pandas

I am creating a dataframe like below

```
df1 = df =pd.DataFrame({'Month_Year':['January_208','January_208','January_208','Febuary_208','Febuary_208'],
                  'Date':['11','11','12','15','15'],
                  'Video_Name':['17-29_202100000.avi','17-29_2055500000.avi','17-29_202150000.avi','17-29_202145000.avi','17-29_202100000.avi'],
                  'Video_Length':['55:11:12','222:10:05','22:02:01','11:00:03','34:20:32'],
                  
})
```

so the dataframe is like[image]
now want to add time of `video_length` column wherever month_year and date is same and want to append those value in new column of datafram i.e. `total_time`
for example for 1st and 2nd row we have same month and date we want to add both time and append in new column total_time similarly for 4th and 5th row .Expected output
[image]

Comment: Can you add expected output? How looks new column finally?

Comment: @jezrael i have updated how the new columns should look like

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`to_timedelta`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.to_timedelta.html) for convert values to timedeltas, then use [`GroupBy.transform`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.transform.html) with `sum` for new column filled by aggregated values and last change format by custom function of final `timedelta`s:

```
df1['Video_Length'] = pd.to_timedelta(df1['Video_Length'])

def format_timedelta(x):
    ts = x.total_seconds()
    hours, remainder = divmod(ts, 3600)
    minutes, seconds = divmod(remainder, 60)
    return ('{}:{:02d}:{:02d}').format(int(hours), int(minutes), int(seconds)) 
    

df1['Total_time'] = (df1.groupby(['Month_Year','Date'])['Video_Length'].transform('sum')
                        .apply(format_timedelta))
print (df1)
    Month_Year Date            Video_Name    Video_Length Total_time
0  January_208   11   17-29_202100000.avi 2 days 07:11:12  277:21:17
1  January_208   11  17-29_2055500000.avi 9 days 06:10:05  277:21:17
2  January_208   12   17-29_202150000.avi 0 days 22:02:01   22:02:01
3  Febuary_208   15   17-29_202145000.avi 0 days 11:00:03   45:20:35
4  Febuary_208   15   17-29_202100000.avi 1 days 10:20:32   45:20:35
```

Comment: hii thanks this is working what changes to do if we want one more column say total_month where it gives the sum of whole month video length suppose fr 1st three row we have january so it will will add all three video_length of og 3 rows and form a new column

Comment: @k_p - Then use `df1['Total_time_monthly'] = (df1.groupby(['Month_Year'])['Video_Length'].transform('sum')
                        .apply(format_timedelta))`

Comment: df1['Video_Length'] = df1['Video_Length'].apply(format_timedelta) line at the end will remove the days and keep the original time format